# Is there anyway to manage HDD behind a Dell PERC H330 controller?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dell-perc

I recently took over ownership of a PowerEdge T330 in my company.
With this server, I realize that the previous administrator did not install many of the drivers and/or management tools.
I was tasked with maintaining the server as well as putting up requests to buy more HDD if there is not enough space. I've read somewhere in the online manual stating that I cannot mix SAS and SATA HDDs together in the RAID setup.

In the past, I was more familiar with how I could use Intel RST console to see what kind of HDD was present and what kind of RAID configuration it was using.

I was wondering if there is anything similar to Intel RST to help me monitor the server HDDs for health status and the like?

Comment: Look for "Dell Systems Management - OpenManage Software"

Comment: http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverId=NPM7F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can set up, configure, and manage your Dell PowerEdge RAID Controller (PERC) by using the Command Line Interface (CLI).

and will find more information in the [Dell PowerEdge RAID Controller CLI Reference Guide](http://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/dell-sas-hba-12gbps_reference-guide_en-us.pdf).

Or you may install the Dell EMC OpenManage Server Administrator (and as mentioned by @[boboes](https://serverfault.com/users/237665/boboes)) in his former comment.

Comment: I'm not too good with Command Line interface I'm afraid. I'll try out the Dell EMC OpenManage Server Administrator. Thanks to both of you.