# megacli commands return exit code: 0x00 with PERC H200

Tags: dell-perc, lsi, megacli

Megacli does not want to talk to a PERC H200 adapter on one of our systems.  This is what happens (all commands run as "root"):

```
megacli -AdpAllInfo      -aAll


Exit Code: 0x00
```

System description (I did not configure this system):

```
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
Rocks release 6.2 (SideWinder)
```

Relevant (probably) dmesg lines:

```
DMI: Dell Inc. PowerEdge T110 II/015TH9, BIOS 1.3.1 11/10/2011
PERCPU: Embedded 30 pages/cpu @ffff880028200000 s90968 r8192 d23720 u262144
mpt2sas0: Dell PERC H200 Adapter: Vendor(0x1000), Device(0x0072), SSVID(0x1028), SSDID(0x1F1D)

megacli -v
      MegaCLI SAS RAID Management Tool  Ver 8.07.14 Dec 16, 2013

lspci -v
01:00.0 Serial Attached SCSI controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic SAS2008 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-2 [Falcon] (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Dell PERC H200 Adapter
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
        Memory at c1440000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Memory at c1400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
        Expansion ROM at c1700000 [disabled] [size=1M]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [68] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [a8] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [c0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=15 Masked-
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [138] Power Budgeting <?>
        Kernel driver in use: mpt2sas
        Kernel modules: mpt2sas
```

All other megacli commands tried return nothing but "Exit Code: 0x00".

Is some other tool needed to talk to an H200?

Answer (score 1):

Stealing the answer from [Is there anyway to manage HDD behind a Dell PERC H330 controller?](https://serverfault.com/questions/915574/is-there-anyway-to-manage-hdd-behind-a-dell-perc-h330-controller), as it's directly applicable here.

> > You can set up, configure, and manage your Dell PowerEdge RAID Controller (PERC) by using the Command Line Interface (CLI).
>
> and will find more information in the [Dell PowerEdge RAID Controller CLI Reference Guide](http://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/dell-sas-hba-12gbps_reference-guide_en-us.pdf).
>
> Or you may install the Dell EMC OpenManage Server Administrator

Try using the tools available from Dell to manage your Dell card. Yes, it's a rebranded LSI card, but the custom Dell firmware running on the card is designed for interfacing with Dell management tools.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Installed perccli (after fixing rpm, because var was completely full) `./opt/MegaRAID/perccli/perccli64 show
Status Code = 0
Status = Success
Description = None

Number of Controllers = 0
Host Name = xxx.xxx.xxx
Operating System  = Linux2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64`.  Now what???

Comment: Well, you're running a BIOS version released six years ago (latest version was in March of this year), so I'd start with updating that and the Lifecycle Controller. I'd suggest updating the PERC driver and firmware as well, but this card doesn't even have a driver release for RHEL/CentOS 6 to begin with (this generation of server and PERC card were only certified with RHEL 4 and 5).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.

According to this post:
https://topic.alibabacloud.com/a/dell-server-megacli-command-returns-only-exit-code0x00-problem-analysis_8_8_31339846.html, the reason is that

> MegaCli64 not support SAS 6i/r

Why SAS 6I/R RAID information is not available with the MegaCli64 command, is also explained in the post.

In this case, we can use the "perccli" command as a substitute for "MegaCli64"

https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/nl-nl/000177280/how-to-use-the-poweredge-raid-controller-perc-command-line-interface-cli-utility-to-manage-your-raid-controller

The perccli can be downloaded and installed as following:

```
wget "https://dl.dell.com/FOLDER04830419M/1/perccli_7.3-007.0318_linux.tar.gz"
tar -xzf perccli_7.3-007.0318_linux.tar.gz
cd ~/perccli_7.3-007.0318_linux/Linux
alien perccli-007.0318.0000.0000-1.noarch.rpm
```

then an installation file will be generated: perccli_007.0318.0000.0000-2_all.deb

```
apt-get install ./perccli_007.0318.0000.0000-2_all.deb
```

We can run `/opt/MegaRAID/perccli/perccli /call show` to get the hard disk information.

Besides, it seems that "lsiutil" can do something similar as well.